# Interview Question : Find the middle element of the INFINITE long linked list?

Tags: linked-list

This question was asked in **Flipkart**.

I had given this solution:

*Traverse linked list using two pointers. Move one pointer by one and the other pointers by two. When the fast pointer reaches the end slow pointer will reach the middle of the linked list.*

But the interviewer said there is another solution I searched the whole internet but couldn’t find the solution.

If anyone knows the solution please let me know.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but if the list is "infinite" then, you won't reach its end would you?

Comment: This was the exact question which he asked I sometimes think the interviewer tricked my mind or this question has a genuine solution. @Michael

Comment: In my understanding, you can't reach something that does not exist. If we are talking about a limitless list, it means that it has no end and as a result, it has no middle.

Comment: Agreed. The half of infinite is still infinite, i.e. not countable. And so you cannot identify a node that is half of infinite, as it will always have a finite number of nodes preceding it. This is what I would answer if I were asked such a thing during an interview. It would be a different story if the question spoke about an *unknown* size of the list, so that your solution must work with *any* size of list -- which is what you did with an elegant solution. The "other" solution could be that you just iterate once to get the size, and then do a second iteration until half of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you got was not well phrased. The concept of an infinite linked list is problematic:

- It has no last node. If there were one, the list would not be infinite.
- It has no middle node. All nodes in a linked list have a finite number of nodes preceding them: also a potential middle node. As there are an infinite number of nodes following it, there are always more nodes following it than preceding it.

There are a few ways to re-interpret this problematic notion:

1. If the list has a cycle, then you *could* call it infinite, although it does not have an infinite number of nodes, it has no *last* node. Then the issue is what the definition is of "middle". It could be the node at offset /2 when there are  *unique* nodes. An algorithm similar to yours (using a slow and fast pointer) can be used to detect the cycle (when the fast pointer overtakes the slow pointer) and thus the number of unique nodes, ...etc.
2. If the list has an *unknown* length. Then I feel "infinite" is a misnomer, as the list is finite, but it could have any length. This is how you interpreted the question, and your answer is an elegant solution.

   An alternative, less elegant solution is to traverse the list once to count the nodes, and traverse it again to stop at the node that has a position half way that count.

In an interview I would raise the problem of the notion of an infinite list, and ask for clarification.